# Google Maps Embed http/https match error

Tags: html, http, google-maps, https

Im trying to embed a google maps map in my website and it works fine, however google chrome is throwing an error.

The error is "Blocked a frame with origin "https://maps.google.co.uk" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.huntinghall.co.uk".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match."

Is there any way I can fix this? the page is at http://www.huntinghall.co.uk/website2013cottages/Contact-Travel

Comment: Does it work to just plain embed an http link to google maps instead of an https one?

Comment: They both work, I just get the error. And i worked out my image wasnt loading because i had the wrong path :-s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at [adding a google map tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map). Don't add the map as an iframe, use Googles methods.

Comment: It is googles method. I simply copied the link it gave me when i clicked on "embed".

Comment: Ah, I just looked at that tutorial. looks like a better way of doing it. Odd, though, that they use an iframe in the embed code...

Answer (score 1):

@jflogvit's suggestion is correct. Alternatively, you should be able to just leave off the http or https protocol and have a url that looks like "//www.example.com/". It's a perfectly valid URL and can work in either http or https protocol/scheme ([more info](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/)).